# Is it possible to use OwnerChangeOptions with the REST Api?

Tags: rest-api, rest, owner

I often change the Account Owner in my salesforce objects using the REST Api. I want to use the OwnerChangeOptions, for example `TransferAllOwnedCases`. But so far I have only found how to do it using the SOAP Api: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_ownerchangeoptions.htm

Is there any way to do it using the REST Api?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

A new [advanced Change Owner invocable action](https://unofficialsf.com/advanced-change-owner-configuration-now-available-in-flow-and-apex/) has just been published here. Once this is installed into your org, you can access it by calling the standard invocable action REST interface.